# Is there a way to read links with in a table cell along with values using pandas and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a table that has rows and each row has 6 columns. I have read the values in the columns and added them to a dataframe but there are links in column 1 and column 6 which i also want to add. I admit that i am new to python. i need help.

I have already tried creating a new dataframe and storing the link in first column but the rows in both dataframes are not coming equal.

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

COLUMNS = ['Legal Name', 'Status', 'Size', 'Suburb or Town', 'State', 'ABN']
COLUMNS2 = ['Link1']

urls = []
for i in range(3):
     quotepage = "https://www.acnc.gov.au/charity?items_per_page=60&"
     quotepage = quotepage + "facet__select__field_beneficiaries=0&"
     quotepage = quotepage + "facet__select__field_countries=0&"
     quotepage = quotepage + "facet__select__acnc_search_api_sub_history=0&"
     quotepage = quotepage + "facet__select__field_status=307&"
     quotepage = quotepage + "page="+str(i)+"#search"

     #print (quotepage)
     urls.append(quotepage)

i=0

dataframes = []
dataframes2 = []

cy_data = []
cy_data2 = []
for url in urls:
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html5lib")
    pagetable = soup.find('table')
    rows = soup.find("table").find_all('tr') 

    time.sleep(.5)
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td") 
        cells = cells[0:6] # Select the correct columns
        cy_data.append([cell.text.strip() for cell in cells])

    links = pagetable.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        if len(link["href"]) == 41:# href for charity
             cy_data2.append(link["href"])

dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS).drop(0, axis=0))
dataframes2.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data2, columns=COLUMNS2).drop(0, axis=0))
#data = pd.concat([dataframes, dataframes2], axis=1)
 data = pd.concat(dataframes)
 data2 = pd.concat(dataframes2)
```

I want to add the links to the dataframe, thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't drop the zero index from the DataFrames, like so:

```py
dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS))
dataframes2.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data2, columns=COLUMNS2))
```

And change finding the *table rows* code to:

```py
rows = soup.find("table").find("tbody").find_all('tr')
```

**Result:**

```
DataFrame 1  [180 rows x 6 columns]
DataFrame 2  [180 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I am an MBA trying my hands on python. thanks a lot. Cant express my thanks. I was so stuck

Comment: @faisal Glad that I could be of help. Kindly, accept the answer, maybe it will help someone facing similar issue.